# Filtering file names with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to make the LGPLv3 licensed software components of my embedded Linux distribution available to adhere to the licensing term. I'm using Yocto to build my root file system. The reference manual has a [nifty script](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#providing-the-source-code) which I adopt:

```
#!/bin/bash
src_release_dir="source-release"
mkdir -p $src_release_dir
for a in tmp-glibc/deploy/sources/*; do
        for d in $a/*; do
                # Get package name from path
                p=`basename $d`
                p=${p%-*}
                p=${p%-*}
                # Only archive GPL packages (update *GPL* regex for your license check)
                numfiles=`ls tmp-glibc/deploy/licenses/$p/*LGPLv3 2> /dev/null | wc -l`
                if [ $numfiles -gt 1 ]; then
                        echo Archiving $p
                        mkdir -p $src_release_dir/$p/source
                        cp $d/* $src_release_dir/$p/source 2> /dev/null
                        mkdir -p $src_release_dir/$p/license
                        cp tmp/deploy/licenses/$p/* $src_release_dir/$p/license 2> /dev/null
                fi
        done
done
```

The issue is I can't seem to get this script to detect files like this:

```
~/build/build$ ls tmp-glibc/deploy/licenses/qtlocation/*LGPLv3
tmp-glibc/deploy/licenses/qtlocation/LICENSE.LGPLv3
```

Help!?

**[Update]**
Fixed a few things with help of [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) and added 'echo':

right before 'if':

```
#!/bin/bash
src_release_dir="source-release"
mkdir -p $src_release_dir
for a in tmp-glibc/deploy/sources/*; do
        for d in $a/*; do
                # Get package name from path
                p=$(basename "$d")
                p=${p%-*}
                p=${p%-*}
                # Only archive GPL packages (update *GPL* regex for your license check)
                numfiles=$(ls tmp-glibc/deploy/licenses/"$p"/*LGPLv3 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
                echo "$p"
                if [ "$numfiles" -gt 1 ]; then
                        echo Archiving "$p"
                        mkdir -p $src_release_dir/"$p"/source
                        cp "$d"/* $src_release_dir/"$p"/source 2> /dev/null
                        mkdir -p $src_release_dir/"$p"/license
                        cp tmp/deploy/licenses/"$p"/* $src_release_dir/"$p"/license 2> /dev/null
                fi
        done
done
```

I'm running this from here:

```
$ ls
bitbake-cookerdaemon.log  downloads  lgpl.sh   source-release  sstate-cache  tmp-glibc

$ ls tmp-glibc/deploy/sources/
allarch-oe-linux  arm-oe-linux-gnueabi  x86_64-linux
```

Output:

```
 ./lgpl.sh                                                                                       
bt-enable                                                                                                                     
ca-certificates                                                                    
eth0-up                                                                               
iso-codes                                                                   
liberation-fonts                                                                 
linux-firmware                                                      
matrix-gui-apps-images                                                                                                          
matrix-gui-submenus                                                                                                                
os-release                                                                                                               
packagegroup-arago-tisdk-graphics                                                                                             
packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh                                                      
run-postinsts                        
.
.
.
```

Comment: A lot of unquoted variables, which will fail because of word splitting and the likes..., try `shellckeck.net`  to verify that script.

Comment: Give us the path of the directory where you execute the script, please.  As pointed out above, a few bad practices seem to be at play here; one not mentioned before is that you use relative paths as in `tmp-glibc/deploy/licenses/$p/*LGPLv3`, so yeah ... show us where you execute your script and what's in "$p". Just for starters.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Please see my updates!